# Vuex persist authenticated status

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Vuex and Laravel sanctum to authenticate users. The following is my Vuex `auth.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

    namespaced: true,

    state:{
        authenticated: false,
        user: null
    },

    getters:{
        authenticated (state) {
            return state.authenticated
        },

         user (state) {
            return state.user
        }
    },

    mutations:{
        SET_AUTHENTICATED(state, value){
            state.authenticated = value
        },

        SET_USER(state, data){
            state.user = data
        }
     },

    actions:{
        async login ({commit}, credentials){
         await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
          await axios.post('/api/login', credentials).then(response => {
                commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED', true)
                commit('SET_USER', response.data)
            }).catch(() => {
                commit('SET_AUTHENTICATED', false)
                commit('SET_USER', null)
            })

        },


    }

}
```

The authentication is working but everytime I refresh the page the authentication status is defaulted back to false. How do I ensure that if the user is authenticated the authentication status remains true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're getting back a **token** from your API, you could store this in the local storage.

```js
state: {
    authenticated: false,
    user: null,
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
},
actions:{
    await axios.post('/api/login', credentials).then(response => {
        const token = response.data.token
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    })
}
```

You could handle an expired token via [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) interceptors:

```js
created () {
    this.$axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.$store.dispatch(logout)
        }
        throw err;
      });
    });
}
```

Vuex logout action

```js
logout({commit}){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('logout')
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    resolve()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible options to persist data: you could use cookies or local storage. Both options are frequently used, for example by [Nuxt Auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/).

An easy option to persist the store would be to use `vuex-persist`. You can find the getting started guide [here](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist).

Comment: I used Vuex-persist with Laravel Sanctum to persist auth, but when the session expire, Vuex-persist still keeps my store as authenticated do you have a solution about that ??

Answer (score 0):

@studio-pj. I don't think it is safe to store a token in LocalStorage because it are user credentials.
Everywhere i read about LocalStorage is that it shouldn't be used for login credentials and other security sensitive data.